# Get values form XML using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to get values from a XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DeviceStorage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Objects>
    <Object Type="OBJECT_ANALOG_OUTPUT" Instance="5">
      <Properties>
        <Property Id="PROP_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_OBJECT_ID">
          <Value>OBJECT_ANALOG_OUTPUT:5</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_OBJECT_NAME" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING">
          <Value>B'JC2415'DUV'Y1</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_OBJECT_TYPE" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED">
          <Value>1</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3006" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED">
          <Value>3</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_DESCRIPTION" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING">
          <Value>Analog out Y1</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3001" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_OBJECT_ID">
          <Value>201:54</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_PROFILE_NAME" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING">
          <Value>7-BA-PX-AO-SBCv10.02</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3121" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING">
          <Value>Building</Value>
          <Value>JET-C2.4-15</Value>
          <Value>DUV</Value>
          <Value>Analog out Y1</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3234" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING">
          <Value>B'JC2415'DUV'Y1</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_PRESENT_VALUE" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_STATUS_FLAGS" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_BIT_STRING">
          <Value>0000</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_EVENT_STATE" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_RELIABILITY" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_OUT_OF_SERVICE" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_BOOLEAN">
          <Value>False</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_UNITS" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED">
          <Value>98</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_RESOLUTION" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0.1</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_PRIORITY_ARRAY" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_NULL">
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
          <Value />
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_RELINQUISH_DEFAULT" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_COV_INCREMENT" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0.1</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_TIME_DELAY" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_UNSIGNED_INT">
          <Value>1</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_NOTIFICATION_CLASS" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_UNSIGNED_INT">
          <Value>32</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_HIGH_LIMIT" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>100</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_LOW_LIMIT" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_DEADBAND" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0.5</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_LIMIT_ENABLE" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_BIT_STRING">
          <Value>11</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_EVENT_ENABLE" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_BIT_STRING">
          <Value>111</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_ACKED_TRANSITIONS" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_BIT_STRING">
          <Value>111</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_NOTIFY_TYPE" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_EVENT_TIME_STAMPS" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CONTEXT_SPECIFIC_DECODED">
          <Value>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM;1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM</Value>
          <Value>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM;1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM</Value>
          <Value>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM;1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_DEVICE_TYPE" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING">
          <Value />
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3000" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING">
          <Value />
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3005" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED">
          <Value>4</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3059" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED">
          <Value>81</Value>
          <Value>6</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>104</Value>
          <Value>4</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>35</Value>
          <Value>10</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>36</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>130</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>3011</Value>
          <Value>10</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>45</Value>
          <Value>10</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>59</Value>
          <Value>10</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>25</Value>
          <Value>10</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>113</Value>
          <Value>4</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3122</Value>
          <Value>10</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3114</Value>
          <Value>10</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>17</Value>
          <Value>7</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>72</Value>
          <Value>10</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>3243</Value>
          <Value>7</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>3014</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>3015</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>3019</Value>
          <Value>8</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3017</Value>
          <Value>4</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>3018</Value>
          <Value>4</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>3123</Value>
          <Value>4</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3124</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>3023</Value>
          <Value>8</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3054</Value>
          <Value>4</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>3055</Value>
          <Value>4</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>3126</Value>
          <Value>8</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>3021</Value>
          <Value>8</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>52</Value>
          <Value>10</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>85</Value>
          <Value>2</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>3211</Value>
          <Value>2</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>3210</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>111</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>103</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>87</Value>
          <Value>5</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
          <Value>3236</Value>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <Value>3</Value>
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3074" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED">
          <Value>5</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3126" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_UNSIGNED_INT">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3008" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3009" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>100</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3114" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_UNSIGNED_INT">
          <Value>3</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3211" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3011" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_BOOLEAN">
          <Value>False</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3014" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_DATETIME">
          <Value>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3015" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING">
          <Value />
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3016" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_NULL" />
        <Property Id="3019" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING">
          <Value>T=1.1</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3017" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>100</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3018" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3021" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_ENUMERATED">
          <Value>2</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3023" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING">
          <Value />
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3054" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0.01</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3055" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3210" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_BOOLEAN">
          <Value>False</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3123" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_UNSIGNED_INT">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3124" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3122" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_UNSIGNED_INT">
          <Value>2</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3212" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0.1</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_MAX_PRES_VALUE" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>100</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="PROP_MIN_PRES_VALUE" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_REAL">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3236" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_BOOLEAN">
          <Value>False</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property Id="3243" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_BOOLEAN">
          <Value>False</Value>
        </Property>
      </Properties>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</DeviceStorage>
```

It has multiple `<Object> </Object>` pairs.
My code can get the tag but can't get the value inside `<Value></Value>`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlfile = 'AS01.xml'

tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

lst = tree.findall('Objects/Object/Properties')

for item in lst:
    for prop in item:
        obj_tag = prop.attrib['Tag']
        obj_value = prop.get('Value')
        print(obj_tag, obj_value)
```

For each `<Object>` I need the values for `Type` and `Instance`:

```
<Object Type="OBJECT_ANALOG_OUTPUT" Instance="5">

OBJECT_ANALOG_OUTPUT
5
```

And several values based on Property Id, for example:

```
<Property Id="PROP_OBJECT_NAME" Tag="BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING"><Value>B'JC2415'DUV'Y1</Value>

PROP_OBJECT_NAME
B'JC2415'DUV'Y1
```

Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

EDIT:

This is how I solved the problem. I's not nice, but works for me:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlfile = 'AS01.xml'

tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

PROP_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER = ''
PROP_OBJECT_NAME = ''
PROP_DESCRIPTION = ''
BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING = ''

def format_string(obj_ident, obj_name,obj_desc,obj_addr):
    # Format the recovered values so I can pipe them into CSV files
    OBJECT_IDENTIFIER=''
    OBJECT_INSTANCE=''
    OBJECT_PATH=''
    OBJECT_NAME=''
    OBJECT_BUS=''
    OBJECT_ADDR=''
    
    str_colon = ':'
    str_apo = '\''
    str_eq = '='

    if str_colon in obj_ident:                      # Separate Identifier and instance number
        cnt = obj_ident.rfind(str_colon)
        cntp = cnt+1
        OBJECT_IDENTIFIER = obj_ident[0:cnt]
        OBJECT_INSTANCE = obj_ident[cntp:]
    if str_apo in obj_name:                         # Separate object path and name
        cnt = obj_name.rfind(str_apo)
        cntp = cnt+1
        OBJECT_PATH = obj_name[0:cnt]
        OBJECT_NAME = obj_name[cntp:]
    if str_eq in obj_addr:                          # Separate address type and the actual addres
        cnt = obj_addr.rfind(str_eq)
        cntp = cnt+1
        OBJECT_BUS = obj_addr[0:cnt]
        OBJECT_ADDR = obj_addr[cntp:]
    print(OBJECT_IDENTIFIER,',',OBJECT_INSTANCE,',',OBJECT_PATH,',',OBJECT_NAME,',',OBJECT_BUS,',',OBJECT_ADDR,',',obj_desc)
    

for obj in tree.findall('Objects/Object'):
    for prop in obj.findall('Properties/Property'):
        obj_id = prop.attrib['Id']
        obj_tag = prop.attrib['Tag']
        
        lst = prop.findall('Value')                 # Check for Value field
        lst_count = len(lst)                    
        if lst_count > 0:                           # If Value field exists
            obj_value = prop.find('Value').text
        elif lst_count == 0:                        # If Value field is missing
            obj_value = ''

        if obj_id == 'PROP_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER':      # Select only the necessary objects
            PROP_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER = obj_value
        if obj_id == 'PROP_OBJECT_NAME':
            PROP_OBJECT_NAME = obj_value
        if obj_id == 'PROP_DESCRIPTION':
            PROP_DESCRIPTION = obj_value
        if obj_id == '3019':
            BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING = obj_value

    format_string(PROP_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER,PROP_OBJECT_NAME,PROP_DESCRIPTION,BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING)
    PROP_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER = ''
    PROP_OBJECT_NAME = ''
    PROP_DESCRIPTION = ''
    BACNET_APPLICATION_TAG_CHARACTER_STRING = ''
```

Output:

```
OBJECT_ANALOG_OUTPUT , 5 , B'JC2415'DUV , Y1 , T , 1.1 , Analog out Y1
OBJECT_ANALOG_OUTPUT , 6 , B'JC2415'DUV , Y2 , T , 1.2 , Analog out Y2
OBJECT_ANALOG_OUTPUT , 7 , B'JC2415'PVV , Y1 , T , 1.3 , Analog out Y1
OBJECT_ANALOG_OUTPUT , 8 , B'JC2415'PVV , Y2 , T , 1.4 , Analog out Y2
```

Comment: Upload a smaller XML doc and explain what are the values you want to extract form it.

Comment: you want `item.text`?

Comment: @balderman this is a redacted XML with only one object section. In the real document the object is multiplied by hundreds.
diggusbickus The problem is some elements has the '.text' others don't. And this is my first try with XML.

Comment: I can see you already have a solution. Nice. Do you still have issues?

Comment: @balderman I don't have anymore. The code runs without errors and the output is as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I get the question correctly but for the values I would go for:

```
values = [i.text for i in tree.findall('.//*/Value')]
```

and for the "Object" properties:

```
types=[i.get('Type') for i in tree.findall('.//*Object/[@Type]')]
instances=[i.get('Instance') for i in a.findall('.//*Object/[@Instance]')]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the necessary push in the right direction.